# Follow path constraint deforming mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bezier-curves

I have rigged a mesh and then I've added a curved path I'd like it to follow. Next, I've added a path constraint to the armature and everything works fine except for one thing: when the mesh rotates to follow the path's curve it is heavily distorted towards the curve's direction.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: did you check the FOLLOW CURVE option in the constraint? cause it should be unchecked

Comment: can you post an image that shows what you describe?

Answer (score 3):

I fought this today and found the issue was one of the axes of my path was scaled to something other than $(1.0,1.0,1.0)$, which I assume happened from my resizing the path. Any objects that followed the curve got the path's scale applied to their geometry. To fix it I did Object -> Apply -> Rotation & Scale on the path, and my troubles went away.

Comment: Exactly what I had. Your answer solved it! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

enabling **Follow curve** option  in the **follow path** constraint force the mesh to deform according to the path "like a curve Modifier does" :

[image]

to follow the curve without a distortion :

- add an empty with a **follow path** constraint on the same path
- adjust the **offset** of the **follow curve** of the object  " 1.00 or according to your path"
- add a **locked track** constraint to the object and set the **target** to the Empty object
- keep adjusting the **offset** till you get a nice result

Comment: I would like my mesh to rotate in the direction of the curve, but if I check follow curve it just deforms in that direction. Do you know if there is any way that it could rotate without deforming?

Comment: follow curve should be unchecked

Comment: In [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html) it says `follow curve` only owner's rotation is modified by the curve. Why the deformation?

Comment: IMHO this is not the issue with OP's question.